# Display unicode character in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following unicode for a char:

```
0x023D2A
```

How do I display it using:

```
textField.text = ???;
```

I have have the name of the character. Can I reference it by name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
textField.text = String.fromCharCode(0x023D2A)
```

Answer (score 3):

textField.text = "Adobe\u00ae" should give you "Adobe®". Replace your Unicode as required.
(Note: I don't have Flash with me where I am; I am posting the above untested.)

Answer (score 1):

Tested whybird's syntax: it works. You can use \u plus the unicode value in hex inside the string.